# Cannot create directory while installing titan.core in cygwin by the command make install

Tags: installation, cygwin, titan

Getting Error while installing the **titan** in **cygwin** with the command **make install** as **cannot create directory ‘D:\cygwin64’: No medium found** * as below.

**Error Details**

```
mkdir -p C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/bin
cp ttcn3_profmerge.exe C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/bin
mkdir -p C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/man/man1
cp ttcn3_profmerge.1 C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/man/man1
mkdir -p C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/include/RT1
cp RT1/TitanLoggerApi*.hh C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/include/RT1
cp: target 'C:cygwin64homeSUBBARAMAIAHInstall/include/RT1' is not a directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:295: install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/core'
make: *** [Makefile:77: install] Error 2
```

I'd appreciate help in understanding the cause of and solution to this error. Thanks.

Comment: why 'D:\cygwin64' as your Cygwin installation is under Disk C and its POSIX root is '/' ?

Comment: I have checked and again installed the cygwin in Disk C (C:\cygwin64) , but still the same error as below. Thanks.

cp RT1/TitanLoggerApi*.hh C:\cygwin64\home\SUBBARAMAIAH\Install/include/RT1
cp: target 'C:cygwin64homeSUBBARAMAIAHInstall/include/RT1' is not a directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:295: install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/SUBBARAMAIAH/titan.core/core'
make: *** [Makefile:77: install] Error 2

Comment: go back to to your question and re-write it with more details: what software are you trying to install (a name is not enough, there are too many with the same name) so an URL will be useful. What instruction are you following and let us know step by step your commands, expected results and real outcome. At first glance you are wishing to install on Cygwin a program that is NOT Cygwin aware and that thinks it is installling itself on plain Windows. We are NOT in front of your computer and we have no clue of the details of what you are doing. Help us to help you

Comment: Thank you , i will update the issue am facing or will raise a new question.